# Insert or skip option for Azure Data Migration tool

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, data-migration, azcopy

I'm currently using the Azure Data Migration tool to migrate from Table storage to Cosmos and I am looking for a way to identify whether a record exists or not in order to avoid duplicate expenditure of processing -- my expectation is that that skipping existing records will save time.

I prefer to use the tool over AzCopy because it's a more streamlined process from what I can tell. However after having reviewed the docs for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-import), I haven't come across a way of id'ing existing records with it. I'm looking for something like the ["InsertOrSkip"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#entityoperationinsertorskip--insertormerge--insertorreplace) flag that's available in AzCopy.

Is there an equivalent in the Data Migration tool that perhaps just hasn't been called out explicitly in the guide?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research on the [Azure Data Migration tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool), no such "Insert or skip" mechanism in it.

However, maybe I could provide you with two workarounds.

The first one, you could use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) service to implement your data transmission.Make the [table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage) as source and make the [cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db) table API as sink. You could write query SQL in [azureTableSourceQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage#copy-activity-properties) property to filter duplicate data.

The second one, you could use [Azure Function CosmosDB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function). Any increment of data will trigger the method to check if the data already exists in the database. If so, then delete.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, Jay. I haven't had a chance to try your suggestion yet, but I will update as soon as I have a chance!